# Django Customize Auto Generated Input button

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

I have a ModelForm to upload an image. My view handle it, upload works. But i want to crop the  image with a javascript. The javascript needs to be called on the " input ", in order to retrieve the picture. Something like this :

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="handleFileSelect()" />
```

I checked by inspecting the code generated by Django for the  ' input' and it looks like this :

```
<input type="file" name="idPicture" accept="image/*" required="" id="id_idPicture">
```

so i'd like to add the onchange to the input. How can i do that ? Is this even possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `jquery` selector

**For example**:

```
$('#id_idPicture').change(function {
   # do your stuff
})
```